# Oracle: Weighted hierarchical sum

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a parent/child structure like this:
|feature | parent_feature | weight | val

Only the lower level has 'val' set.
'weight' is the relative importance of the feature for the parent_feature as, the sum(weigth) of all immediate childs of a parent_feature is 1.

The goal is to produce a table showing the calculated 'weight x val' (calc_val) for each feature and parent feature. Each line should show 'calc_val' as being either 'weight x val' - for the lowest level - or, sum('weight x val') of all immediate childs - for all other levels up to the top.

Any help?
Thanks.

EDITED: Added data and expected results

**Schema (PostgreSQL v12)**

```
create table feature (name varchar, id int);
insert into feature (name, id) values ('root',0);
insert into feature (name, id) values ('f1',1);
insert into feature (name, id) values ('f2',2);
insert into feature (name, id) values ('f3',3);
insert into feature (name, id) values ('f4',4);
insert into feature (name, id) values ('f5',5);
insert into feature (name, id) values ('f6',6);

create table feature_parent (feature_id int, parent_id int, weight decimal, val int);
insert into feature_parent (feature_id,parent_id, weight, val) values (6,4,0.5,10);
insert into feature_parent (feature_id,parent_id, weight, val) values (5,4,0.5,20);
insert into feature_parent (feature_id,parent_id, weight) values (4,1,0.3);
insert into feature_parent (feature_id,parent_id, weight,val) values (3,1,0.3,10);
insert into feature_parent (feature_id,parent_id, weight,val) values (2,1,0.4,30);
insert into feature_parent (feature_id,parent_id, weight) values (1,0,0.5);
```

---

**Expected results**

```
| feature_id | parent_id | calc_val|  
| ---------- | --------- | ------  | 
| 1          | 0         | 19.5    |  (calc_val (4) x weight 4) + calc_val (3/2)
| 2          | 1         | 12      |  weight x val
| 3          | 1         | 3       |  weight x val
| 4          | 1         | 15      |  sum(calc_val) of immediate childs
| 5          | 4         | 10      |  weight x val
| 6          | 4         | 5       |  weight x val
```

All branches have weights, relative to their parent. That's why F4 has a weight. But, once a node has children, it no long has 'val', as it should be calculated from its children.

Once that node (e.g. F4) has a 'val' (calculated from its children) then, we must multiply it by its weight to carry on with the calculations and use that to sum with its siblings.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A DB/SQL fiddle is also very helpful.

Comment: Please can you clarify the logic being used as it doesn't seem to be consistent e.g. F4 = F5+F6 = 10+5 = 15 - in which case why has F4 got a weighting of 0.3 as this isn't being used. By the same logic, F1 should be F2+F3+F4 (the sum of its children) = 12+3+15=30 but you have it as 19.5

Comment: I'm probably making this more difficult to understand than it should be, but I'll try to clarify:

All branches have weights, relative to their parent. That's why F4 has a weight. But, once a node has children, it no long has 'val', as it should be calculated from its children.

Once that node (e.g. F4) has a 'val' (calculated from its children) then, we must multiply it by its weight to carry on with the calculations and use that to sum with its siblings.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to solve this using any type of pure SQL query as it requires you to start at the "leaf" level and work up to the root rather than the other way round - and at each parent you would have needed to calculate all its child branches already i.e. you can't follow a single path from leaf to root. I think you would need to write PL/SQL to do this: I would write a hierarchical query to give you the level for each node, store this in a table and then loop through all the levels, starting at the largest number, calculating the values for each node.

Comment: I'm not limited to using pure SQL. I would prefer that but, we can not make the world spin the other way around, can we ? :-)

Comment: If you write some PL/SQL and get stuck them I'm happy to help. I can also provide some pseudo-code to get you started with how I would do it, if you want. Happy for someone else to help if they want to write PL/SQL for you

Comment: Any help would be very much appreciated Nick. Even pseudo-code would be helpful at his time.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic pseudo-code (and a bit of real SQL) to show how I would approach this challenge:

1. Run a hierarchical query to get the "level" of each feature. Save these levels to a table along with all the other data you will need:

   SELECT
   feature_id,
   parent_id,
   weight,
   val,
   level
   FROM
   feature_parent
   START WITH parent_id = 0
   CONNECT BY PRIOR feature_id = parent_id;
2. Loop through all the feature records, starting at the lowest level, and calculate the values:

   FOR i = max(level) to 1 STEP -1
   SELECT records where LEVEL = i
   IF val is not null then calc_val = weight*val
   ELSE calc_val = calculated from child records
   NEXT i